# Ria Services : Use Entity Framework Code First Classes From Another Project

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, ef-code-first, wcf-ria-services

I have a solution with this structure :

> ProjectName.Domain ==> contains POCO classes (EntityFramework
>   code first classes) 
>  ProjectName.DataAccess ==> contains DbContext
>   and EntityFramework mapping codes. 
>  ProjectName.Task ==> It's my
>   bushiness layer . 
>  ProjectName.Presnetation.MvcClient ==> It's
>   ASP.NET MVC web client. 
>   ProjectName.Presentation.SilverlightClient ==> It's Silverlight 5
>   client. 
>  ProjectName.WCFRiaClassLibrary ==> It's layer between
>   business logic and Silverlight client

I've decided to handle logic such as queries and CRUD operations in business logic and use ProjectName.Task in domain service class.

I can't find any sample that use EF code first approach and load entities from another project , can you please help or give me link ? because when I try to create my DomainService class without wizard I can't find generated proxy classes in silverlight client project . 
I'm doing something like this :

```
    [EnableClientAccess()]
    public class CrudService : DomainService
     {
    private readonly IEntityTask _entityTask;

    public CrudService(IEntityTask entityTask)
    {
        _entityTask = entityTask;
    }

    public IQueryable<Entity>  GetAll ()
    {
       return _entityTask.GetAll().AsQueryable();
    }
    }
```

Is this possible to use code first classes from another project with WCF Ria Service ? 
What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defintely possible. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059127/ef5-code-first-and-ria-services-silverlight-object-reference-not-set-to-an-inst) to see possible problems with wcf ria + ef
**EDIT:**
I've just written a small blog post attaching to it a functional project. You can find it [here](http://mcasamento.blogspot.it/2012/10/entity-framework-5-code-first-and-wcf.html)

Comment: My problem is not as same as linked question.

Comment: does your domain context is being generated ? does your class define KeyAttribute ? btw, the linked question is all about problems about classes not being generated on the proxy